# Magento system.log keeps writing even if it is disabled

Tags: magento

In my magento store, i have disabled logging, however the system.log keeps getting bigger because magento writes to it. How do i force the system to not write to system.log?

Comment: Did you clear your Magneto cache after updating your configuration?

Comment: Yup this i did as the first thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento Admin > System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings and set the «Enabled» option to No. Make sure you are setting this option for all stores and websites.

Check if you have not left something like this in your code: Mage::log('');

Clear all caches. Delete existing system.log or simply rename the existing file.

It will not log anymore.

Hope this helps!!